# Python I can't open file 'app.py' in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, flask, backend

I was using flask to develop a Python project. It was working fine to start the backend program via `python3 app.py` under the `backend_code/` directory. 
However, when I tried it today, it showed

```
my_user_namedeMBP:backend_code my_user_name$ python3 app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/my_username/folder_name/**project_name/app.py**': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is the project structure:

```
+-- folder_name
    +-- project_name
      +-- frontend_code
      |
      +-- backend_code
          +-- app.py
```

It works well when I moved back to directory `folder_name/` and run `backend_code/python3 app.py` but I try not to do that because it  will cause some files path reading in my backend code invalid.
I dn't understand I started the interpreter and run app.py under directory `backend_code/` but the error message shows that it is looking for app.py under `project_name/` which obviously cannot find app.py (It is under `project_name/backend_code/`).

The only thing I can recall which might cause this issue is I updated my pip from 9.* to 12.* (I downgraded it already but error still persists).

Other information might be useful:

I am using vscode.

```
  pip -V => pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
  pip3 -V => pip 9.0.3 from 
   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6) 
  python --version => Python 2.7.15
  python3 --version => Python 3.6.5
```

Could anyone tell me what I should do? Why is that？ Appreciate your help!!

Comment: can you show us the cwd you are trying to run `app.py` in? if you are in the `project_name` directory you'll need to `cd ..` to go to `folder_name` and then just cd `backend_code` and run the app.

Comment: @Patch Thank you for your reply. The cwd is ```/Users/user_name/folder_name/project_name/backend_code
``` and this is the directory I wish to run app.py using ```python3 app.py```. It usually works well.

Comment: By your error that you got you weren't in this directory.

Comment: Yes, that confuses me. I am pretty sure I am in that directory, otherwise the it will show "app.py not found " at the begining.

Comment: Did you try to run it in cmd?

Comment: Yes, I am running it in cmd. Btw, I am using mac.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same sort of error, using Dash app (which is based on Flask).

As far as I got is that it could be related to `sys.path.append` in my several `.py` files. But if I do not have this path appended I cannot load some functions in other folder (which is a DB helper).

Anybody have any idea how to solve this?

I'm using Ubuntu, VS Code and anaconda.

Thank you for you help.

EDIT with solution:
I was able to fix the issue if I run werkzeug's `run_simple` instead of the native `app.run_server` which is a development server (as noted above with the warning):

```
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple("0.0.0.0", 8050, app.server, use_debugger=True)
```